# Report showing the conversion rate of all events per page in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have created events with the action names as subscribe and download. The category of these events are the path of the pages where they are triggered.

```
Category | Action    | Total events
/page1     subscribe   1,000
/page1     download    100
/page2     subscribe   1,000
/page2     download    150
/page3     subscribe   1,000
/page3     download    50
...
```

I have many categories (many paths) and I would like to know the percentage of how many users subscribed actually download a content.

```
/page1  100/1,000 = 10%
/page2  15%
/page3  5%
...
```

How can I do this? I have looked into Custom Dashboard or Custom Reports but I can't find the way. Maybe I am doing wrong using events for this.